# Provider 'LeaderboardService' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I have this file leaderboard.service.js:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('App42')
        .factory('LeaderboardService', LeaderboardService);

    LeaderboardService.$inject = ['App42Service'];
    App42.initialize();

    function LeaderboardService(){
        var result ;
        var gameService  = new App42Game();

        gameService.getAllGames({
            success: function(object) {
                var game = JSON.parse(object);
                result = game.app42.response.games.game;
                console.log("result is " + result)

            },
            error: function(error) {
            }
        });

    }
})();
```

And i really do not know how to and were to write the return statement with function that will return, in this case i would simply like to return the list of games. Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thin you miss the return statement. 
You should return your service object, like: return gameService.

Comment: I have added the return like this: .... },
            error: function(error) {
            }
        });
        return gameService;
    }
})();

Comment: after i have added this line, the error does not appear and i see in logs some data. Is it ossible for you to explain to me, how can i show those data on html page? i have a controller but i can not understand how to use data gotten in factory in a controller (which is a separate file)